# Does python scrapy work properly on localhost?

Tags: python, scrapy

I have written a scrapy spider to scrape out some html tags. Now the problem is that this spider works perfectly for a url that is running on internet but not for a url that is on localhost. What i mean is, the spider produces error for a url of the resource on local computer even when the url is perfectly correct and works correctly for the same resource when url for the running site.
Can someone clear this doubt of mine?

```
    def parse(self, response):
    hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
    con = MySQLdb.connect(host="localhost",
                          user = "username",
                          passwd="psswd",
                          db ="dbname")
    cur = con.cursor()
    title = hxs.select("//h3")[0].extract()
    desc = hxs.select("//h2").extract()
    a = hxs.select("//meta").extract()
    cur.execute("""Insert into heads(h2) Values(%s )""",(a))
    con.commit()
    con.close()
```

Comment: What error does it produce?  Are you using a `http:` url for the local-computer resource, or a `file:` url?

Comment: Hey Brooks. I have used http: url for locahost and have also added my code. In this code. The error that is produces is:  title = hxs.select("//h3")[0].extract()
 exceptions.IndexError: list index out of range

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error

```
exceptions.IndexError: list index out of range
```

on this line

```
title = hxs.select("//h3")[0].extract()
```

indicates that the list `hxs.select("//h3")` is empty (`[]`) since attempting to access the first item (index 0)  with `hxs.select("//h3")[0]` uses an index which Python tells us is out of range.

The html you are parsing apparently has no `<h3>` tags.

---

Also, after you fix the above error, you'll need to put a comma after the `a` in `(a,)`:

```
cur.execute("""Insert into heads(h2) Values(%s )""",(a,))
```

`(a)` is evaluated to `a`, whereas `(a,)` represents a tuple with 1 element inside.

Comment: well this exactly is the problem. This same code works perfectly for non localhost urls and produces errors on urls with localhost. What might the reason be?

Comment: Inspect the HTML (either through print statements, or reading the file, or using a browser's ability to view source). Something is different about the HTML being returned by the different servers.