# Scrapy just stops unexpectedly with no error

Tags: scrapy, web-crawler

every time Scrapy just stop after running a few minutes and I still cant figure out why ?
**spider added 69** , is that too much spiders ? There are indeed lots of ParseException... Any help will be appreciated.

**stop like this** :

```
2014-12-01 12:34:06+0800 [scrapy] INFO: info : {'platform_name': '\xe7\xa7\xaf\xe6\x9c\xa8\xe7\x9b\x92\xe5\xad\x90', 'platform': 'jimubox', 'loanId': '13774', 'create_time': 1417408354133}    exception : ParseException('type', 'list index out of range')
2014-12-01 12:34:06+0800 [scrapy] INFO: info : {'platform_name': '\xe7\xa7\xaf\xe6\x9c\xa8\xe7\x9b\x92\xe5\xad\x90', 'platform': 'jimubox', 'loanId': '13773', 'create_time': 1417408354133}    exception : ParseException('type', 'list index out of range')
2014-12-01 12:34:07+0800 [eloancn] INFO: Crawled 19 pages (at 19 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2014-12-01 12:34:09+0800 [qmdai] INFO: Crawled 10 pages (at 10 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
```

scrapy version : 0.24.4

Comment: Well, there is a `ParseException` being raised. Might be related.

Comment: There are indeed lots of ParseException , any suggestions ? @alecxe

Comment: Could you add your code ? The parse exception may be related to an error in the crawling/parsing class. Have a look at other similar posts (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9143597/does-python-scrapy-work-properly-on-localhost)